# SSIS Error: ADO NET Source failed to acquire connection - Could not create a managed connection manager

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ado.net, ssis-connection-manager

I am unable to execute my SSIS package in Visual Studio.
I am guessing that it might be some kind of a compatibility issue as things were running fine before my software upgrades.

I have used a ADO.NET connection manager to connect to Azure SQL database. The connection is successful and I can also get a preview of the result from the ADO.NET Source Editor.

However, when I execute the package it throws the below error during runtime:

> [ADO NET Source [2]] Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {5F0461B3-FE8C-4E2C-997D-B39A72BA5571} with the following error message: "Could not create a managed connection manager.".

My software versions are as follows:

1. Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.5.1
2. SQL Server Data Tools  17.2.40118.0
3. SQL Server Integration Services   16.0.5131.0
4. SQL Server 12.0.2000.8 (Azure SQL)

Please note that previously I was being able to connect to the Azure SQL database through Provider - .Net Providers\SqlClient Data Provider.
However, now after the re-installation, I could only connect through .Net Providers\Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider.

Rest everything is the same. What is the difference between these?

Can someone please help me out here? Really appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before you started upgrading software did you uninstall anything? If it was working before and it's not working any longer then it suggests that you uninstalled a required database provider/driver. What are the connection details of the failing connection manager?

Comment: Actually I did not upgrade anything but since my organization upgraded my OS to Windows 11, I had to install Visual Studio and SSIS once again. I installed the latest ones of those.
Connections details are:

Provider: .Net Providers\Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
Server name: xxx.database.windows.net
Authentication: Active Directory Password Authentication

Comment: What versions of .NET Framework do you have installed on the machine that's throwing the error message? Possibly you were using System.Data.SqlClient before, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is the modern replacement, but it currently requires a minimum of .NET Framework of 4.6.2 to be installed.